# Jimp : how to use new filename as parameter of write function?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Jimp module of NodeJS to do some image transformation in my (big) nodejs script inside a big loop where my filename is dynamically generated.

When doing my jimp image transformation, the filename provided to write function parameter is already changed. Because the write is inside a callback (so a another thread?) and my loop is already continue to process another loop step.

Here is an example overview:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var filename = 'test' + i + '.png';
    //some script to generate my image : pupperteer screenshot of a webpage

    Jimp.read(filename).then(function (image) {
        image.greyscale().write(filename);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

In this example, my script create the file test1.png in color, then I can view a test2.png appear which is a copy of test1.png but in greyscale... Then it overwrite by a new color image named test2.png.

So I'm wondering how to solve this?
It's perfectly fine to have it in multithread, so how to use a copy of "filename" string to use it in parameter of write function?

Regards

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use let instead of var

```
let filename = 'test' + i + '.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with asynchrony. I think that you could create a method and send filename as param. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    let filename = 'test' + i + '.png';
    //some script to generate my image : pupperteer screenshot of a webpage
    _saveImg(filename);
}

function _saveImg(name) {
    const filename = name;
    Jimp.read(filename).then(function (image) {
        image.greyscale().write(filename);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

=)